# How to make the style of a MenuStrip like that of the MenuStrip in Notepad? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

and I was wondering if there was a way to get this style of MenuStrip:

[image: older style]

in a WinForms application, instead of this style:

[image: newer style]

I've already tried browsing through the different appearances Visual Studio offers, but I think it might be the version of the .NET framework I'm using, which is 4.5, I'm fairly certain.

Edit: Sorry, I should have said this before, but I'm using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: hi there, just use standard theme, don't use other 3rd party, it should give you natural look like standard win form

Comment: @JunRikson That doesn't work, I'm afraid. :/

Comment: it will be help if you provide your visual studio version and windows version for peoples to check on their own. Because in my windows 10, the notepad MenuStrip doesn't look like that

Comment: @JunRiksonI Updated question.

Comment: I'm so sorry I don't have your kit. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 :/
Hope someone can help you.

Comment: @JunRikson I've found it, but thanks for your effort <3. The answer was pretty simple, actually. I feel rather silly for not thinking of it.

Comment: That is good :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. Just simply replace a MenuStrip with a ToolStrip, and but the RenderMode property to "System". I feel rather silly now heh

Comment: A `ToolStrip` isn't the right choice, but rather a [`MainMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mainmenu?view=netframework-4.7.2) which creates a native Windows menu. It can be added to the Tool Box by right-clicking it and selecting `Choose items...`, then browsing for it in the `.NET` tab.

Comment: The MainMenu does this, but ToolStrip with the right settings produces the exact effect I was looking for anyways so there's no need to edit the toolbox items.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.Right click on toolbar and click Choose Item.Now select .Net Framework click Main Menu.
Now use it. But I have windows 7 and visual basic 2010 express...